# Reference to main thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, reference, program-entry-point

How do I get a reference to the main thread from another thread in C# ?

Why this is needed ? Take for example an assembly loaded to a console application. This assembly raises another thread that wants to wait (join) on the main thread of the console application. How will it do that ?

I thought of this way: In visual studio 2010 you can inspect threads information while debugging. One of the columns in the threads window is the category that specifies if the thread is a worker thread or main thread. Is it possible to get this information ?

Or this way: What about getting the name of the function which is the entry point (main thread ?) and than iterate all threads in current process. How can I obtain this information ?

Thanks.

Comment: "This assembly raise another thread that want to wait (join) on the main thread of the console application. How will it do that ?" - typically, the main thread will join the other thread, not the other way around. I've never seen a need for what you're talking about.

Comment: That's the Thread Name, not a category

Comment: What about reflection on the assembly for the entry point. can somebody figure out how to find the entry point method ?

Answer (score 2):

You can store a reference to `Thread.CurrentThread` (which would be the main thread) in creation of another thread.

Comment: look at the comment for Andray's response

Answer (score 1):

No thread is actually main. After you spawn more threads it stops being important which one is main. The only way to find out which thread was created first is to save reference to it in some global static field.

Comment: So what is the UI thread then??  Surely **UI thread** is what is meant by "Main Thread". I do not agree with you.

Comment: @Aliostad: The UI threads are the threads currently calling `Application.Run`.  Technically, they're no different from other threads.

Comment: @SLaks yes true, but what they do is very different. Handling WIN32  message loop happens in them so they need to be treated differently.

Comment: well, the whole point of this question was: what to do if you have no access to the main thread, like when your code is in DLL that is loaded by others executable.

Comment: @Aliostad @Vertilka every thread can theoretically handle message loops. they are indistinguishable.